# Paths repetitions more than a specific number

Tags: prolog

There was 8 rooms more specific a room, b room, c room, d room, e room, f room, g room, h room. The question was, it shows me a draw and was asking me every door of the room shouldn't be more repetition than 4. How should it be this code? What I did was:

```
 %the directions
    next_to(a,b).
    next_to(a,c).
    next_to(a,d)
    next_to(b,a).
    next_to(b,h).
    next_to(c,a).
    next_to(c,d).
    next_to(d,a).
    next_to(d,c).
    next_to(d,f).
    next_to(e,d).
    next_to(e,g).
    next_to(h,b).
    next_to(h,g).
    next_to(g,e).
    next_to(g,h).
    next_to(g,f).
    next_to(f,d).
    next_to(f,g).
    %i did for two ,i mean not to repeated more than 2 times, but the exercise asking me no more than 4
   %i did a loop here smaller than 4 ,i know its wrong.
    calc(L, NL):-
      include(in_range, L, NL).

    pathloop(Start, End, _, [Start, End]) :-
        next_to(Start, End).
    pathloop(Start, End, Visited, [Start|PathRest]) :-
        next_to(Start, Second),
        not(member(Second, Visited)),
        pathloop(Second, End, [Second|Visited], PathRest).



    in_range(X):-
      number(X),
      (X > 0 ; X < 4)
```

.

Comment: I don't see how `calc` fits in with your `pathloop` predicate.

Comment: i edited may it is better